# xslt1.0 to convert dateTimeto YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert a date received in xs:dateTime format to  YYYY/MM/DD  input received is : 2002-05-30T09:00:00
 Output expected 2002/05/30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `substring-before()` and `translate()`...

```
translate(substring-before(normalize-space(),'T'),'-','/')
```

Full example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>2002-05-30T09:00:00</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before(normalize-space(),'T'),'-','/')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>2002/05/30</doc>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxy

Comment: Thnks . I will try this